# Asymptotics of $(n+1)^{-(1+a)} H_n^{(-a)}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, harmonic-numbers

Interested by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276114/limits-of-summation-of-power-series/2277546#2277546), running cases, I have been able to *observe* that, for any value of $a$ (positive integer, rational, irrational, complex)
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^a}{n^{a+1}}= \frac{H_n^{(-a)}}{(n+1)^{a+1}} =\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{a}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ I wonder how this could be directly obtained since all my attempts have been totally unsuccessful.

All ideas and suggestions will be very welcome.

Comment: Isn'it readily obtained from Faulhaber's formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: @RenéGy. I forgot to precise that this is for any value of $a$ (integer, rational or irrational). I shall edit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  though you probably already know this, probably worth noting that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^a = \frac{1}{n^{-1-a}} - a\int_1^n\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^{1-a}}dx = \frac{1}{n^{-1-a}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^{a+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\left(k+1\right)^a$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It may be possible to extract some information from that integral by generalizing the method in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352733/reference-for-proof-of-harmonic-number-asymptotic-expansion), which handles the case $a=-1$ (i.e. the harmonic numbers)